# Bash script: Can we create a local variable, but not using a function? How?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is it possible to create a local variable in a script, but without using a function?
I saw that we can't just use `local variab=1`.
Any solution?

Comment: You can just write `var=value`. Unless you use `export`, it would be invisible to outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shell variables which are not marked as exported are local to the shell they are created in. Exported variables are copied into subshells; strictly speaking, they are not really shared with the subshells because changes are still local to the shell in which the change is made.

However, some shell constructs are not subshells. In particular, function execution does not cause a subshell to be created, and neither does the `source`/`.` built-in. In functions (but not in `source`d files) you can make a variable local by declaring it to be local.

If you want to make a shell variable local to a block within a script, you can create a subshell using the `(…)` syntax:

```
a=outside
(
  # This is a subshell, so the following is local
  a=inside
  echo $a
)
# Back to the outer shell
echo $a

{
  # This is **not** a subshell, so the following affects the outer a
  a=braced
}
# Here, a has changed
echo $a
```

Comment: It seems the subshell thing helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by local.

If you mean local to a function, obviously that makes no sense without a function.

But if you mean local to the script, then

```
variable=value
```

creates a variable not visible in the environment of processes you start, unless you `export` it.

Furthermore, you can create subshells within one shell script (e.g. using ()) and again in there, that creates a new process so variables will be local to that process.

Comment: It seems the subshell thing helps :)